# Accidentally did something, and now everything is sheer/translucent?

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine

Here's an image as an example. I don't know what I did and ctrl-Z is not helping. This is for a project that's due tomorrow, so please help ??? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Try ALT + Z or Shift + Z

Comment: emir i owe you my life thank u so much shift-z worked! my project will be completed!

Comment: Emir must be a magician....!!!!! :D

Comment: @Chris I've pressed Alt Z but now my room is half transparent in real life and Ctrl Z doesn't do anything   :((

Comment: @moonboots: always look on the bright side of life....do the same thing at your hot neighbour's house...and enjoy watching! :D

Comment: @ Chris, oh ok it works, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @moonboots : does it let you walk through walls though? :^)

Comment: @ John Eason yes if the normals are correctly flipped!